# Need help regard running my first android app in my mobile?

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm trying to write my first android app (android studio 2.2). I tried it using the emulator and it works fine. When i connected my Samsung J1 ace running android v 4.4.4 it appears in the "Select Deployment Target" but when i choose it and press ok the following message appears

[image]

[image]

Why does the android studio want to download android 1?

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Are you really targetting Android 1.0?!

Comment: Have you defined the target SDK in the manifest or gradle file?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, actually i changed the phone and it works with the new one

Answer (score 0):

please update your SDK From api level 15 to till now

Comment: 15 seems like a random thing number based on the information given

Comment: And change you build.gradle target version  compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.smaat.virtualtrainer"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

Comment: Please [edit] your post to have that as a code block